# Vim line number combination remapping

Tags: vim

Can I remap so that typing g312 instead of 312g ? I want to push some key, then enter line number to go, not vice versa. I don't have F* keys on my laptop, so I want to utilize number keys as functional keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the command mode `:` to achieve this without remaps.

```
:312
```

would fly you to line 312. Additional benefit: you can have command mode specific mappings to have digits available if that would be easier with the function key situation.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's exactly what i'm going to do: map numbers in command mode to have the functions I previously had with function keys